# Handbrake Video Codec for H.263

Tags: video, mp4

For some devices (older Android phones), I need MP4 with Baseband H.263.

Handbrake has only codec options for H.264, MPEG-2, MPEG-4.

Is there a trick to use H.263 with handbrake, too, or how do you handle this task usually? I read lots of threads in stackexchange and everyone is using handbrake, but I can not find the right codec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handbrake leverages several flexible open source libraries and presents a great, usable front end. However, it only exposes the most common features that most people care about. As you have discovered, H.263 is not one of those features that many care about in this day and age.

The good news is that the underlying code (the FFmpeg software) can encode several different types H.263 video. You can try using FFmpeg directly from the command line to do the conversion.